# How do I create subcollections in firestore with php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, php-7.1

I'm looking to create [this firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eexi.png) with this version of PHP

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.10-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2017 17:33:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
      with Zend OPcache v7.1.10-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c)
1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

This is my code:

```
$path = "/xxx/firebase_auth.json";
$config = array(
    "projectId" => "test",
    "keyFile" => json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true)
);
$firestore = new FirestoreClient($config);
$collection = $firestore->collection('clients');
$trips = $collection->add([
    'organization_id' => '3'
]);

// this line throws an error when /employees is appended to path
$document = $firestore->document('clients/'.$trips->id().'/employees');

// this block works when '/employees' is removed from document path
// but it places the data in the document, not the '/employees' subcollection
$firestore->runTransaction(function (FirestoreTransaction $transaction) use ($document) {
    $transaction->create($document, [
        ['path' => 'roles', 'value' => array(
            "IT Manager" => "John",
            "Sales Manger" => "Jane",
            "Customer Service Manager" => "Jack",
            "Accounting Manager" => "Jill",
            "Managers" => 4
            )
        ],
        ['path' => 'office_location', 'value' => array(
            "latitude" => 40.7406375,
            "longitude" => -74.0107935
            )
        ],
        ['path' => 'country', 'value' => 'USA'],
    ]);
});
```

And I get this error when I run it:

```
Exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Given path is not a valid document path.'
in /vendor/google/cloud/src/Firestore/FirestoreClient.php:248
```

I did read up on Google Firestore subcollections here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model, and from that page:

> To understand how hierarchical data structures work in Cloud Firestore, 
>     consider an example chat app with messages and chat rooms.
>     You can create a collection called rooms to store different chat rooms.
>     Now that you have chat rooms, decide how to store your messages. You might not 
>     want to store them in the chat room's document. Documents in Cloud Firestore 
>     should be lightweight, and a chat room could contain a large number of 
>     messages. However, you can create additional collections within your chat 
>     room's document, as **subcollections**.

However, I am using Google Firestore's PHP SDK, and subcollections are not mentioned: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.53.0/firestore/transaction

I just need an example on how to create a subcollection with Firestore's PHP SDK, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly create subcollections. Create a reference to a subcollection and you can start adding documents.

You probably don't need a transaction if you're just creating a single document:

```
$employeesCollection = $firestore->collection('clients/'.$trips->id().'/employees');

$newDocument = $employeesCollection->add([
        ['path' => 'roles', 'value' => array(
            "IT Manager" => "John",
            "Sales Manger" => "Jane",
            "Customer Service Manager" => "Jack",
            "Accounting Manager" => "Jill",
            "Managers" => 4
            )
        ],
        ['path' => 'office_location', 'value' => array(
            "latitude" => 40.7406375,
            "longitude" => -74.0107935
            )
        ],
        ['path' => 'country', 'value' => 'USA'],
    ]);
```